# Users changing date/time from BIOS

Tags: time, date

We have around 350 Windows XP PC and a Windows 2008 R2 Server. The problem is that some users are changing the date/time from BIOS and the next user who would try to log-in on that PC would get the date/time server difference error.

We tried to protect the Bios with a password but if we set an Administrator password they can't just skip that by pressing Intro and would enter in User mode (which is allowed to change date/time). If we set an User password, the same will be asked every time the PC is turned on (useless for us cause all the devices are turned off at 1 am).

I'm looking for a GPO to force a date/time update BEFORE the user log-in.

Comment: I read this as 'Some users are purposefully sabotaging PCs.'. In which case a technical solution is nice, but the real answer is to kick those users.

Comment: What Hennes said - this is a human resources problem.  Tell them to stop it or they'll be subject to disciplinary action.  (Also - why the hell are they changing the time *anyway*?)

Comment: I dont really know why the are doing this, as I said in an answer, they are 95% between 18 and 21 years old working in a call center... I know that is a HHRR problem too, but we need to find out who is doing this, and seems to be pretty imposible since we are only 2 IT and there are no ITs member on the night-shift, so they have free way...

Comment: You cannot lock down the BIOS on regular PCs unless you are at the station itself

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the BIOS to see if there is an option to move changing the date/time from user mode to admin mode. Send out an email telling user's that if they change the date/time, they will break their own computer.

Comment: There are not more settings in Bios and would be pretty difficult to do that (if exists) in 350 since we'r only 2 IT. Sending that kind of email will be useless (this is a call center). Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think such an email would be useless? I've found that user's are generally fairly good for following instructions to not do something if they understand it is in their own interest.

Comment: I dont know, may I should try that. I just know that as being a call center the 95% of the people are between 18 and 21 years old... recently graduated from school, you know. But I will try. Thank you again!